# Basic Authentication with RestTemplate on outbound gateway

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, apache-httpcomponents

Been pulling what little hair I have left trying to get this to work.

***Problem 1***:

I am performing a JSON POST to a Spring controller. I pass in the `Authentication` header as a parameter to the `int:gateway`. An `int-http:outbound-gateway` then gets invoked. I can see the header and also the handshake with the remote application, but I am getting a `400 Bad Request` from the `org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient`. I am able to authenticate and execute the request directly (i.e. without SI) using a separate client.

I used components mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19655352/1990536) solution unsuccessfully. Where am I going wrong with this?

What I do not like is the reference to `DefaultHttpClient` which appears to be deprecated as mentioned in other posts. Not sure what the alternative is here. Somewhere I saw mention of using `OkHttp` client, but I am not sure how to wire that up with SI.

***Problem 2***:

The service below returns a `ResponseEntity<?>` because I am unable to convert it to the domain specific type (CustSyncResponseVO). Should I expect this behavior when using RestTemplate with SI or is there a transformation I can perform on the `outbound-gateway` response?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Environment**

- Java 1.7
- Spring Boot 1.3.1.RELEASE
- HTTP Core v4.3.2 and HTTP Client v4.3.5

  ```
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  ```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customerSync", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody CustSyncResponseVO syncCustomer(@RequestBody CustSyncRequestVO customerSyncRequest, 
        @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String authorization ) {
    CustSyncResponseVO customerSyncResponse = null;

    customerSyncResponse = customerService.deliver(customerSyncRequest, authorization);

    return customerSyncResponse;
}
```

**Service**

```
package com.uscs.crm.service;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Header;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.uscs.crm.integration.CustomerGateway;
import com.uscs.crm.model.CustLinkRequestVO;
import com.uscs.crm.model.CustSyncRequestVO;
import com.uscs.crm.model.CustSyncResponseVO;

@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomerServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private CustomerGateway customerGateway;

    @Override
    public CustSyncResponseVO deliver(CustSyncRequestVO custSyncRequest, @Header(value="Authorization") String authorization) {
        CustSyncResponseVO custSyncResponse = null;     
        //custSyncResponse = customerGateway.deliver(custSyncRequest);
        ResponseEntity<?> responseEntity = null;
        try {
             responseEntity = customerGateway.deliver(custSyncRequest, authorization);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Unable to sync customer request to eWM" , e);
        } 

        return custSyncResponse;
    }


    @Override
    public CustSyncResponseVO link(CustLinkRequestVO linkRequest) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("To be implemented");
    }

}
```

**Gateway**

```
package com.uscs.crm.integration;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Header;

import com.uscs.crm.model.CustSyncRequestVO;

public interface CustomerGateway {
    public static final String HTTP_AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization"; 

    public ResponseEntity<?> deliver(CustSyncRequestVO customer, @Header(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION) String authorization);

}
```

**Config**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.uscs.**"/> 

<!-- Authorization scope for accessing restful service.  Since we want this template to be used for everything, we are setting up it with defaults --> 
<bean id="authScope" class="org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope">
    <constructor-arg name="host"><null /></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg><value>-1</value> </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg><null /></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg><null /></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="httpComponentsMessageSender" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
    <property name="credentials">
        <bean class="org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials">
            <constructor-arg name="userName"><value>xxxxxx</value></constructor-arg>
            <constructor-arg name="password"><value>xxxxxx</value></constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="authScope" ref="authScope"/>
</bean>

<bean id="clientHttpRequestFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
    <property name="httpClient" value="#{httpComponentsMessageSender.httpClient}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="restTemplate" name="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate" autowire-candidate="true">
      <constructor-arg ref="clientHttpRequestFactory" />
  <property name="messageConverters"> 
      <list> 
          <bean  class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
          <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/> 
          <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
      </list> 
  </property>
</bean>

<int:channel id="syncCustomers"/>
<int:channel id="replySyncCustomers"/>

<int:gateway id="customerGateway" service-interface="com.uscs.crm.integration.CustomerGateway" 
        default-request-channel="syncCustomers" default-reply-channel="replySyncCustomers" />

<int:object-to-json-transformer input-channel="syncCustomers" output-channel="outboundRequestChannel" content-type="application/json" />    

<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="outboundRequestChannel" reply-channel="replySyncCustomers"
              url="http://voorhees148.uscold.com:9595/web/customerSync/createCustomer"
              http-method="POST"
              rest-template="restTemplate"
              expected-response-type="com.uscs.crm.model.CustSyncResponseVO" 
              mapped-request-headers="Authorization, HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS"/>
```

**Logging from SI**

```
10:07:03.981 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Sending request: POST /web/customerSync/createCustomer HTTP/1.1
10:07:03.981 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "POST /web/customerSync/createCustomer HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
10:07:03.981 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Accept: application/json, application/*+json[\r][\n]"
10:07:03.981 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Authorization: Basic aHFyc2luZ2g6UGFzc3dvcmQxMjM=[\r][\n]"
10:07:03.981 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
10:07:03.981 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Content-Length: 431[\r][\n]"
10:07:03.981 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Host: voorhees148.uscold.com:9595[\r][\n]"
10:07:03.981 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
10:07:03.981 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.5 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
10:07:03.981 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "[\r][\n]"
10:07:03.981 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> POST /web/customerSync/createCustomer HTTP/1.1
10:07:03.981 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Accept: application/json, application/*+json
10:07:03.981 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Authorization: Basic aHFyc2luZ2g6UGFzc3dvcmQxMjM=
10:07:03.981 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Content-Type: application/json
10:07:03.981 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Content-Length: 431
10:07:03.981 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Host: voorhees148.uscold.com:9595
10:07:03.981 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Connection: Keep-Alive
10:07:03.981 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.5 (java 1.5)
10:07:03.981 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> ""{\"legacyNo\":\"867530\",\"customerType\":\"24\",\"customerName\":\"Test Customer\",\"addr1\":\"123 Main Street\",\"addr2\":\"\",\"addr3\":\"\",\"city\":\"Podunk\",\"state\":\"MI\",\"zip\":\"48158\",\"country\":\"US\",\"phoneNumber\":\"8563334444\",\"contactName\":\"Jeb A. Dyah\",\"contactType\":\"123\",\"contactPhone\":\"8561112222\",\"contactFax\":\"8567778888\",\"contactEmail\":\"jeb@podunk.com\",\"actionCode\":\"CREATE\"}""
10:07:06.576 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request[\r][\n]"
10:07:06.576 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0[\r][\n]"
10:07:06.576 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1[\r][\n]"
10:07:06.576 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "$WSEP: [\r][\n]"
10:07:06.576 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Content-Language: en-US[\r][\n]"
10:07:06.576 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=0000yf8BRdBUc8w-OZldE5UDJSt:cd3aeb2b-d5ea-4ef6-8a84-9b912f76478c; Path=/; HttpOnly[\r][\n]"
10:07:06.576 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
10:07:06.576 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Connection: Close[\r][\n]"
10:07:06.576 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Date: Sun, 20 Dec 2015 15:07:06 GMT[\r][\n]"
10:07:06.576 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT[\r][\n]"
10:07:06.576 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Cache-Control: no-cache="set-cookie, set-cookie2"[\r][\n]"
10:07:06.576 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "[\r][\n]"
10:07:06.576 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
10:07:06.576 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
10:07:06.576 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0
10:07:06.576 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
10:07:06.576 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << $WSEP: 
10:07:06.576 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Content-Language: en-US
10:07:06.576 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=0000yf8BRdBUc8w-OZldE5UDJSt:cd3aeb2b-d5ea-4ef6-8a84-9b912f76478c; Path=/; HttpOnly
10:07:06.576 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
10:07:06.576 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Connection: Close
10:07:06.576 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Date: Sun, 20 Dec 2015 15:07:06 GMT
10:07:06.576 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
10:07:06.576 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Cache-Control: no-cache="set-cookie, set-cookie2"
10:07:06.577 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.a.h.c.p.ResponseProcessCookies - Cookie accepted [JSESSIONID="0000yf8BRdBUc8w-OZldE5UDJSt:cd3aeb2b-d5ea-4ef6-8a84-9b912f76478c", version:0, domain:voorhees148.uscold.com, path:/, expiry:null]
10:07:06.577 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - POST request for "http://voorhees148.uscold.com:9595/web/customerSync/createCustomer" resulted in 400 (Bad Request); invoking error handler
10:07:06.608 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "2b[\r][\n]"
10:07:06.608 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Error 400: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 400[\r][\n]"
10:07:06.608 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "[\r][\n]"
10:07:06.608 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "0[\r][\n]"
10:07:06.608 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "[\r][\n]"
10:07:06.608 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Connection 0.0.0.0:45624<->192.168.56.1:9595 closed
10:07:06.608 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 0][route: {}->http://voorhees148.uscold.com:9595][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
10:07:06.608 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.i.g.GatewayProxyFactoryBean$MethodInvocationGateway - failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive: HTTP request execution failed for URI [http://voorhees148.uscold.com:9595/web/customerSync/createCustomer]; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
10:07:47.894 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR c.u.crm.service.CustomerServiceImpl - Unable to sync customer request to eWM
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:641) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:597) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:572) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:493) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:382) ~[spring-integration-http-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:150) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:42) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:38) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:79) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:70) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:412) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:386) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:422) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:382) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.deliver(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.uscs.crm.service.CustomerServiceImpl.deliver(CustomerServiceImpl.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.uscs.crm.controller.HelloController.syncCustomer(HelloController.java:35) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_67]
10:07:51.692 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
10:07:51.693 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
10:07:51.693 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.b.c.w.OrderedRequestContextFilter - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@5f525ba5
```

**EDIT1**:

It appears that the remote application logs indicate a problem with unmarshalling the request to the expected type:

```
nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.uscs.ewms.mdm.vo.customer.synchronizer.CustomerCreateSyncSubRequestVO] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method (AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:132)
```

**Controller and Request Type in Remote Application**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createCustomer", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = CONTENTTYPE_APPLICATION_JSON, produces = CONTENTTYPE_APPLICATION_JSON)
public @ResponseBody
CustomerSyncResponseVO createCustomer(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody CustomerCreateSyncSubRequestVO customerCreateSyncRequestVO, Principal principal) {

...

}

public class CustomerCreateSyncSubRequestVO {

@JsonProperty("legacyNo")
private String legacyNo;

...

}
```

There is no default constructor in the remote `CustomerCreateSyncSubRequestVO`, but this unmarshalls from JSON with no problem when I send an HTTP POST directly to the remote application without SI in the middle. I feel that the double quoted JSON "string" that is sent through the `outbound-gateway` is causing the problem since the `400 Bad Request` implies invalid JSON. My request object from the SI gateway does have a default constructor without any other annotation:

```
package com.uscs.crm.model;

public class CustSyncRequestVO {

    private String legacyNo;
...
    public CustSyncRequestVO() {

    }
}
```

Comment: I updated to the latest versions of HTTP Core (v4.4.4) and HTTP Client (v4.5.1), but still no difference. I also explicitly set the `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers to `application/json` via a `header-enricher` to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here is the solution that seemed to work for me:

**Before**:

```
<bean id="restTemplate" name="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate" autowire-candidate="true">
      <constructor-arg ref="clientHttpRequestFactory" />
  <property name="messageConverters"> 
      <list> 
          <bean  class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
          <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/> 
          <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
      </list> 
  </property>
</bean>
```

**After**

```
<bean id="restTemplate" name="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate" autowire-candidate="true">
      <constructor-arg ref="clientHttpRequestFactory" />
  <property name="messageConverters"> 
      <list> 
          <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/> 
          <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
          <bean  class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
      </list> 
  </property>
</bean>
```

This solved both problems I was having as mentioned in the original post. The order of the message converters is important.

I found the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15764371/1990536) post.